# How can I make multiple directories in Mac OS terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I'm trying to make multiple folders at once but when I press enter it says: mkdir: i/like: No such file or directory.

I do this
mkdir i/like/icecream

I think I have the latest version of python.
Any help? Ty.

Comment: The Unix man pages are a valuable resource, although sometimes hard to read. Try `man mkdir` :-)

Comment: Im trying to learn how to use pushd and popd while reading this book: "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way" by Addison Wesley (2017). It tells me this:
cd temp
mkdir i/like/icecream
pushd i/like/icecream
~/temp/i/like/icecream ~/temp
popd
~/temp
pwd
~/temp
pushd i/like and so on... but I get stuck in mkdir i/like/icecream. It works if i enter mkdir i like icecream, but when I enter pushd it says ~/temp/i/ ~/temp only and it should say ~/temp/i/like/icecream ~/temp

Comment: pushd/popd are used for navigation within the directory structure, not for creating directories :-)

Answer (score 10):

The switch -p allows deep folder creation along a path

```
mkdir -p  i/like/icecream/too
```

You don’t need python for this, unless it reminds you of “p” instead of the **pattern** passed in to create ***the full path prefix***.

Comment: At least under Linux the long format of `-p` is `—parents`, so it would be “parents” rather than “path”.

Comment: You've managed to preserve the pattern @Phoenix as well as prompt a correction.

Comment: Not sure really what you mean.  I just looked up the man page on Linux, provided the comment, but it did not feel right to actually change anything in your post as the macOS man page may state something else there.

Comment: @Phoenix BSD: _A mkdir command appeared in Version 1 AT&T UNIX. BSD January 25, 1994._ My guess is linux reimplemented this or took from GNU, but being inclusive  seemed the thing to do. I appreciate your comment here - it made the answer better Sorry for making it sound like you didn't know the score.

Comment: Yep. I’m aware of that.  Used to use MacOS X since 10.4, but moved to Linux after 10.11. I just don’t remember the man page text in macOS. Does it say “path” there?

Comment: @Phoenix It does't give a name to the `-p` option, probably because there is no long form (https://ss64.com/osx/mkdir.html).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then.  BSD leaves it open for interpretation.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Phoenix, macOS **is not** Linux, so what's applicable there is not relevant here! The macOS `mkdir` manpage states, "−p Create intermediate directories as required. If this option is not specified, the full path prefix of each operand must already exist.", so the use of the term _path_ is just fine!

Comment: @user3439894 Not sure what agitates you so much. I have been a long-term macOS user and moved on to Linux after having run Mac OS X 10.11 for some time. I’m aware that Linux is not BSD or macOS and it was stated already by nohillside. My assumption was (and thanks to previous comments that I was wrong) that the man page in BSD/macOS looks very similar for this command as it is one of the base commands for both OSs. I’m happy that i learned something today. However, your comment does not add anything useful here and the pressure depicting agitation is not helpful either.